# Change Orientation to Vertical when use of Repeater

Tags: nativescript, repeater

I am creating a Horizontal scroll in NS. When using below code it's working as expected.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onPageLoad" class="page">
<StackLayout>
    <!-- This is where the magic happens -->
    <ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="scroll-menu">
            <StackLayout class="scroll-pane">
                <Button text="Button" />                  
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="scroll-pane">
                <Button text="Button" />                  
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="scroll-pane">
                <Button text="Button" />                  
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="scroll-pane">
                <Button text="Button" />                  
            </StackLayout>
         </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</StackLayout>
```

Horizontal Scroll:

[image]

But, Once I am using the Repeater it's changing to orientation with Vertical and not scrolling.

```
<Page  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onPageLoad" class="page">
<StackLayout>
    <!-- This is where the magic happens -->
    <ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="scroll-menu">
        <Repeater items="{{ categories }}"  > 
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                <StackLayout class="scroll-pane" >
                    <Label text="{{name}}" />
                </StackLayout>                
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
         </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</StackLayout>
```

Change to Vertical when use of Repeater:

[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Use the [RadListView][1] from Telerik, it has better performance, better documentation, more features and [you can define layouts for horizontal scrollDirection][2].

There is a [GitHub repository][3] full of examples.


  [1]: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/overview
  [2]: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts
  [3]: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular